# Отладка qt приложения на другой машине

Tags: c++, qt, администрирование, devops

Приложение разрабатывается на Windows машине для Linux'а. Можно ли настроить Qt Creator так чтобы код писался на Windows машине, а разрабатываемое приложение запускалось/отлаживалось на linux машине, например на виртуалке?

Comment: Первое, что выдал гугл: https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-developing-generic-linux.html

Comment: Я в таких ситуациях просто переношу код на виртуалку (через удаленную репку и git) и тестирую на виртуалке с нужной осью и нужным окружением.

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко А на русском гугл выдает что-нибудь?